# Submission and pricing of iPhone application to Apple Store

Tags: iphone, submission

I have worked on iPhone application but not aware of the formalities to submit it to Apple Store. Please somebody help me out to solve the following queries:

Are their any submission charge to be paid?
And Procedure to submit application to Apple Store.

Thanks & Regards,
Khushi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've paid to join the developer program, there is no additional charge for actually submitting your application.

When you've logged in with your developer account, instructions for submitting applications should be available following the link Rhys gave.

My advice is **read them very carefully** before submitting, because some things cannot be changed once you've submitted your iPhone application - for example: the name of your app, and whether it will also run on the iPod Touch etc.

Answer (score 3):

The [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/) has all the info you need. Currently priced at $99.

> The iPhone Developer Standard Program provides you access to the App Store where you can distribute your free or commercial application to millions of iPhone and iPod touch customers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one too ---- http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/04/list-guideline-for-submitting-iphone-application-to-apple-store/

Answer (score 1):

If you're a registered developer, Apple provides a very nice and rather thorough video on the App Store submission process. I recommend you watch it. In fact, I recommend everyone doing iPhone development watch ALL the videos on the iPhone Dev Center. They're invaluable.

Comment: we could watch it if you post the link

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the iPhone Developer Standard Program restricted to 100 iPhone devices?
Although you distribute your application on the App store, you can't distribute it to more then 100 decives? 
Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You're talking about 'ad hoc' distribution. It's really designed for beta testing and that sort of thing. And yes, it's limited to 100 devices. Once you submit to the AppStore there's no limit on how many people can download it.